# Why is Python's lxml.etree.SubElement a class method not an instance method?

Tags: python, lxml

In order to add a new sub-element to an existing element, I have to invoke a class method, and give the parent element as an argument.  I would expect creation of a sub-element to be an instance method of the soon-to-be-parent element, with the child-to-be (from the Element constructor) as the only formal parameter.

Actual:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from lxml import etree
root = etree.Element("parent")
childNode = etree.SubElement(root, "child")
```

Expected (imagined):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from lxml import etree
root = etree.Element("parent")
childNode = root.AddSubElement(etree.Element("child"))
```

Is this a decision by the designers of lxml, or constraint imposed by some other part of the lxml design, or "more Pythonic," or what?

Comment: `SubElement` is a factory, not a class method: see http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#SubElement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that, but the method for doing so is called `append`, not `AddSubElement`:

```
childNode = root.append(etree.Element("child"))
```

The [lxml tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-element-class) says that "this is so common that there is a shorter and much more efficient way to do this: the SubElement factory".  However, the example it gives for using `SubElement` is actually slightly longer than the one with `append`, and it doesn't explain how it's more efficient, so I confess I'm stumped about why it says that.  You can use whichever syntax you like more.

It would seem the *real* shorter way would be a method that lets you append by element name instead of creating an Element object manually (e.g., `root.addChild("child")`).  I don't know why there is no such method, but I believe some other XML libraries have something like this.

Comment: If I saw something like `root.addChild("child")` I’d think it was appending a text node with the content `child`.

Comment: @icktoofay: Well, okay, it could be called `.addChildNode` or `.addSubElement` as the OP suggested.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  AFICT, the reason that the tutorial claims that it's shorter is that append doesn't return the value of the appended child, so you need to create the child and then append it, or else get a reference to it after it's created.  Either way, it's two statements.
    `>>> nfd`
    `<Element NFD at 19e70a8>`
    `>>> child = nfd.append(etree.Element("newChild"))`
    `>>> child`
    `>>>`